# How to deal with conflicts when you are working on multiple topic branches?

Tags: git, version-control

I use Github.com and normally create *Topic* branches when I work on a feature or an issue.

Suppose I am working on multiple topics in parallel which deals with shared files (say configuration) that needs mostly code addition at the bottom, I can't sent PR's to Github.com because there is going to be conflict anyways.

For example, imagine I have a common config file C shared by all the modules represented by files M1 ... Mn. I started a Topic branch from master called M1-Feature and did commits to M1 and C (just **appended** some lines to C). Again started a Topic branch from master for M2-Bug and committed to M2 and C (just **appended** some lines to C) so on and so forth. Since C is shared I am getting conflicts due to **line numbers** when I sent this across for final merge. Essentially these PR's are not really valid and I have re-work of which I am actually aware ahead of time.

```
      /----m1-commit----c-commit
master
      \----m2-commit----c-commit
```

So how do I handle this problem of resolving conflicts before hand?

I was thinking of **cherry-picking** the commits to file C, sequentially in the order in which I want it finally in the master, to the topic branches. But it creates a partial state i.e config changes are present but not the code to support it.

```
      /----m1-commit----c-commit(first)
master
      \----m2-commit----c-commit(first-cherry-pick)----c-commit
```

Another way is to keep **rebasing** Topic b with Topic a always. This I think is better. This is basically linearizing all the commits though it is happening in parallel.

```
      /----m1-commit----c-commit(first)
master
      \----m1-commit----c-commit(first)----m2-commit-----c-commit(second)
```

My goal is that the PR's shouldn't waiting for a conflict resolution since I know that before hand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last option (rebasing) is the correct way because even if you have two topic branches which are parallel, **in the moment you want to integrate them into the master you have to decide on an order**. So it is always either Topic A first and then Topic B or Topic B first and then Topic A. So one of them will have to deal with the changes of the other.

For reducing the conflicts of pull requests, I think you have a little problem here because normally you don't know which feature will get integrated first. There is also the possibility that only one of the topic branches will be integrated.
What you can do in this case is to communicate your actions to the person which integrates your pull requests and tell them which order is to be used.

Comment: Yeah I think "order" is an important term to keep in mind. It actually means I am not longer working in parallel as far as Git is concerned but this is just fine.

Comment: And what do you think about first option that was my original solution? It Just an ugly hack though it works? It creates partial modifications which is not good right? [The second one was pointed to me from IRC :-)]

Comment: Yeah there is tight coupling.

Comment: I'm a big friend of **topic branch has only code changes which it needs**, so I think your cherry pick introduces stuff into a topic branch which won't get used and this is a problem in the case your other topic branch won't get integrated. (maybe the feature was not needed anymore,...) Then you have unused code in the master and need to clean that up.

Comment: Note that OP said they want to rebase `topic-A` onto `topic-B`, which is nothing more than cherry-picking all of the commits and is something you've said you disagree with (I do too!). So you might want to be clear that you're talking about rebasing `topic-A` onto `master`, followed by `topic-B` onto `master`, incase OP is confused.

Comment: @Pod regarding the cherry-pick and rebase basically the same: in this case it is not really the same because OP wanted to cherry-pick only the shared stuff. And in the long run you still have your topic branches with rebase and can shuffle them around easier. And i'm not talking about rebasing topic a onto master and the topic b onto master. With this you wouldn't solve the conflicts because you still have two parallel branches.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is no different than normal operating procedure of git. It's designed to deal with multiple branches. It's the reason for its existence.

> This is basically linearizing all the commits though it is happening in parallel.

It's also destroying history. As you say: They happened in parallel.

> My goal is that the PR's shouldn't waiting for a conflict resolution since I know that before hand!

Just use `git merge`.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge M1-Feature 
<deal with any conflicts by editing the files in question>
$ git apply <files you've edited>
$ git commit
$ git push
```

then issue a pull request from your git repo to the one in question

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge M2-Bug
<deal with any conflicts by editing the files in question>
$ git apply <files you've edited>
$ git commit
```

then issue a pull request from your git repo to the one in question

Comment: But this implies that you know that both pull requests will be integrated and that the order of the pull requests is already defined. (Which is also implied with the rebase variant) In the case that M1-Feature isn't going to be integrated but you still want M2-Bug then you need to redo your pull request.

Comment: In this case after the reviewer merges M1-Feature, M2-Bug will become unable to merge because of conflicts since it is taken from master. Are you saying Git is **intelligent** to handle this... I might have to test that out. I want to settle it ahead of time. Can't see how Git can settle the order since everything is parallel.